# Unable to write a txt file to SD card on Android KitKat

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I keep trying to write to the SD card in my java code but whenever i check my card the folder and file isnt there; i know that for KitKat you have to use `.getExternalFilesDir` but so far nothing is working.
my current code:

```
 String DataIn = PhoneNumber + "," + dataLong + "," + dataLat;
        File storageDirectory = new File (this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "location.txt");
        if(!storageDirectory.exists()) {
            try {
                storageDirectory.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String Directory = storageDirectory.toString();
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(storageDirectory, true);
            OutputStreamWriter myoutwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
            myoutwriter.write(DataIn);
            myoutwriter.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Did you add the respective permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You shouldn't have added any permission for this - unlike ordinary ExternalStorage the unique storage location provided by getExternalFilesDir **does not** require a permission as it already "belongs to" your app.  A more appropriate question might be how you are looking for the file to see if it exists.

Comment: Im not looking to see if it exists. i didnt realise it had to, i thought it just created the file and the !.exists() statement would just create it if it didnt find it @ChrisStratton

Comment: What I mean is, how are you determining if the experiment succeeded or failed?

Comment: the toast.() pops up when the button is pressed meaning that the code is being enacted

Comment: and i have my phone connected to the pc so i can view the files

Comment: The problem may be that your PC may not be allowed to view files created in this location, rather than that the file is not being created. You may want to use the primary external storage instead, and remember to invoke the media scanner after writing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Can you please provide a clear example in the form of an answer as to how I can get this to work?

Comment: That would depend on what **exactly** you want to do.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i want to save a string to a .txt file in a folder then just send it to an email. Thats all

Comment: A simple answer would be to use the primary external storage as in jaytj95's answer, or you can use a content provider.  You don't need the involvement of the PC.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Can you be specific

Comment: You have already been given an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File storageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "location.txt");
```

Make sure you have this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i cant do that because KitKat doesnt let you do that anymore; you have to use .getExternalFilesDir()

Comment: @user36606 - you are mistaken.  This API still works in KitKat.  However it continues to access the primary external storage, which may or may not be an sdcard.  For most devices sold today, this primary external storage is part of a soldered-in flash chip, while any sdcard is secondary, and secondary external storage is indeed highly restricted in KitKat.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so is there a way to save files on the external storage so that i can send them or should i just ave it internally and send it from there